# How to view DbgPrint messages from a Windows filesystem minifilter?

Tags: wdk, minifilter, debugview

I am trying to run one of the minifilter samples from Microsoft provided here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/passThrough

I don't know what this minifilter is supposed to do (documentation isn't great), but for starters, if I can just see the output from a `DbgPrint()` statement, I'll be happy.  While running *Sysinternals* *DebugView* as admin, I did `fltmc load passthrough` and `fltmc unload passthrough`, but did not see any output from the filter.  I know that at least the function corresponding to the unload feature in the code has a `DbgPrint()` message:

```
PT_DBG_PRINT( PTDBG_TRACE_ROUTINES,
("PassThrough!PtUnload: Entered\n") );
```

Am I supposed to see these messages? If so, how?  If not, how can I debug minifilter development?

PS: I did define the Registry key suggested here: https://www.danclarke.com/debugview

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from the debugger attached using the:

```
ed nt!Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 0x8
```

Or check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/reading-and-filtering-debugging-messages) link out as you can also enable it from the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've enabled 'Capture Kernel' under the Capture drop-down menu, instead of 'Capture Global Win32' which is what the article you linked us to mentions.

As for the File-System Mini-Filter device driver sample you linked us to, there's plenty of documentation surrounding development of filter-manager drivers available over at MSDN.

If you go into driver development blind with the Microsoft samples, you can't really expect to understand how it all works with a click of a finger... It is very different to user-mode development, you'll be starting from the bottom again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at PT_DBG_PRINT macros in the source code:

```
#define PT_DBG_PRINT( _dbgLevel, _string )          \
(FlagOn(gTraceFlags,(_dbgLevel)) ?              \
    DbgPrint _string :                          \
    ((int)0))
```

There is a condition that checks gTraceFlags variable. By default gTraceFlags is 0. So just set that variable to enable DbgPrint, for example:

```
ULONG gTraceFlags = PTDBG_TRACE_ROUTINES;
```